# Is there a way I can edit a CSS variable via the CSS Class Title?

Tags: php, html, css, less

So I have someone who wanted a special class title to use so they could be able to change the padding of a `div`. I quickly created a class called `.columnpadding` so they could do this. Later I was asked to make a few more classes so they could change the padding across multiple pages. Instead of having to duplicate the css class over and over and change the padding for each, is there a way I could have the variable changed via the class title.

For example.

If the class title is `.columnpadding-100` 
Is there a way to have a class with its padding at 100px?

My website runs on Php and Less. Let me know if the coding would be too complicated. Im hoping its not something too crazy! Thanks!

Comment: Given that the user will have to type in these modified class-names - for the purpose of JavaScript interpretation - have you considered asking them to use, and therefore type in, CSS variables ('[CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)') instead: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gf8hcewo/)?

Answer (score 2):

So let's presume we have the following basic structure:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnpadding-50"></div>
<div class="columnpadding-30"></div>
<div class="dontchangeme"></div>
<div class="columnpadding-10"></div>
```

Using only vanilla JS we can easily achieve the desired result:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='columnpadding-']");

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  let psize = divs[i].getAttribute('class');
  psize = psize.substring(psize.indexOf('-') +1, psize.length);
  divs[i].style.padding = psize + 'px';
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnpadding-50"></div>
<div class="columnpadding-30"></div>
<div class="dontchangeme"></div>
<div class="columnpadding-10"></div>
```

- Where we first select all `div`s containg class with value `columnpadding-` into a NodeList
- Then we retrieve a string of the each class attribute, and `substring` it from the `-` to receive the size
- Last but not least, we apply `style.padding` to our selected elements in NodeList

And *voilà*, produces the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery

CSS - not needed, but here for the example

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="columnpadding-100">This has 100 padding
</div>
<div class="columnpadding-50">This had 50 padding
</div>
```

javascript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // wait until the page is completely loaded
    $("[class^='columnpadding-']").each(function(){ // get every element that has a class starting with "columnpadding-"
        let classNamesString = $(this).attr('class'); // get the string of class nameS from this element
        let classNames = classNamesString.split(" "); // create an array of class names
        $.each(classNames, function(index, className){ // loop through the class names looking for the one we want
            if (className.startsWith("columnpadding-")) { // hey, this is the one we want
                let amount = className.substring(14); // get the amount after the hyphen
                $("." + className).css("padding", amount + "px"); // set the css for the padding on the element
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This has is very interesting! Im definitely looking to do it in Php or Less though. But thanks for this as well, for it is useful!